# Force useEffect to run only once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a MERN stack app in which a user has to verify their account using a link sent to their email address.
After the user clicks on the link, they are sent to this ActivationPage component. Here, I extract the token from the URL and, in a POST request in `useEffect`, send it to the server where the user is created in the database (MongoDB).

Now the issue is that when the component first runs, it returns *"Your account has been activated successfully!"* as it should, however, after a few seconds the message changes to "Your token has expired!" because `useEffect` ran again and tried to created the user again which resulted in an error and hence the catch block ran. So, I basically need a way to make `useEffect` run only once.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import { serverUrl } from '../serverUrl';

const ActivationPage = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const activationToken = searchParams.get('token');

  useEffect(() => {
    const activationEmail = async () => {
      if (activationToken) {
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(`${serverUrl}/user/activation`, { activationToken });
          console.log(response);
        } catch (error) {
          setError(true);
          console.log(`ERROR: ${error.message}`);
        }
      }
    };

    activationEmail();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center'>
      {error ? <p>Your token has expired!</p> : <p>Your account has been activated successfully!</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ActivationPage;
```

Comment: I believe React runs all `useEffect` functions twice in a non-production environment.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes it does that because of the strict mode. But i don't want to disable it just to get around this issue. I need to stable solution for this

Comment: Would using the error variable (from useState) as a dependency in useEffect help in any way???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a ref to store a flag if it was already run.
The reason for using `useRef` instead of `useState` is that we just need a persistent variable and don't want or need to trigger a rerender when changing its value.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import { serverUrl } from '../serverUrl';

const ActivationPage = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const activationToken = searchParams.get('token');
  const wasAlreadyRequested = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const activationEmail = async () => {
      if (activationToken) {
        try {
          wasAlreadyRequested.current = true
          const response = await axios.post(`${serverUrl}/user/activation`, { activationToken });
          console.log(response);
        } catch (error) {
          setError(true);
          console.log(`ERROR: ${error.message}`);
        }
      }
    };
    if (!wasAlreadyRequested.current){
     activationEmail();
    }
  }, [wasAlreadyRequested]);

  return (
    <div className='w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center'>
      {error ? <p>Your token has expired!</p> : <p>Your account has been activated successfully!</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ActivationPage;
```

Comment: That you so much! It's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

this is a the useeffect code
use this code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    first
    return () => {
      second
    }
  }, [third])
```